# The target type of this expression must be a functional interface in MethodReferences

Tags: java-8, method-reference

Why does the following code not compile.

`Consumer con = (s) -> System.out::println;`

It says

> The target type of this expression must be a functional interface

even though Consumer is a Functional Interface. The below works just fine.

`Consumer con2 = (s) -> {System.out.println(s);};`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Because that's a method reference, the usage is a bit different:

```
 Consumer<String> c = System.out::println;
```

The argument that the consumer takes (`s`) will be still passed to the `println` method.

[here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) is Oracle's tutorial on this.

Answer (score 12):

`Consumer con = (s) -> System.out::println;`

Here, you're trying to invoke the `System.out.println()` with what we call *method reference* in Java 8. When you're to reference a method in lambda expression its must be of like this,

`Consumer con = System.out::println;`

You don't actually need the `s` to call `println` method. Method reference will take care of that. This `::` operator means you'll call the `println` method with a parameter and you don't going to specify its name.

But when you do this,

`Consumer con2 = (s) -> {System.out.println(s);};`

you're telling the lambda expression to explicitly println the content of `s` which is perfectly fine technically so it doesn't arise any compile error.